# Show where 2 kids interact with a programmer stuck in his computer

Tags: story-identification, tv

I've been trying to remember the name of this show.  It aired during the 90s sometime.  It logically must have been between 1993 and 1999, but I can't narrow it down any more than that.  It featured 2 or 3 kids (I think there were 2 main and sometimes a 3rd) who had a computer in their attic (or possibly spare room) where a computer programmer had, at some point, been trapped inside.  Occasionally an episode would be about trying to get him out, but usually it was a 'lesson of the day' style format.

There was a character named Glitch who was a ball of glowing light.  The programmer had apparently made him by accident or something, though I could be mis-remembering.

I remember parts of 2 or 3 episodes.  In one, one of the kids was superstitious about an upcoming sports game of some sort (soccer I think, which may mean it was an import as I'm in America), doing various rituals, and the other said that was wrong.  The programmer took the stance that everything can be explained, while one of the programs whose name I can't recall took the opposing stance.  It was ultimately shown that the start of their winning streak corresponded to more rituals, yes, but also to more practicing.  Bizzarely the ending was 'maybe we're both right', which wasn't really what they had showed.

In another, the programmer was trying to escape.  At the end he started to break through the screen but was just a fraction too late.  The screen stretched in a CGI metallic effect into hand shapes, which the kids tried to grab, but then he was thrust back.

It may have been the same episode, but there was one where Glitch kept passing them hints as to why he was stopping something (possibly the escape) and the last riddle featured the line "And admit that I'm worth listening to."  After much stubbornness, the programmer finally admitted "I guess everyone can say something worth hearing.  Even Glitch."

I found the name once like 10 years ago but then forgot again as I didn't write it down.  Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is probably *[Reality Check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality_Check_(American_TV_series))* (1995).

> Reality Check was a 1995 television show starring Ryan Seacrest as Jack Craft, a 19-year-old inventor who gets stuck in his computer mainframe project on June 8, 1995. The two Bonner siblings (Samantha and Nicholas) reactivate the computer on September 17, 1995, attempting to get Jack Craft out of the mainframe, while also encountering additional members of the project.
>
> The show was broadcast under syndication with each episode running for 15 minutes including commercials. It was produced in association with S & S Productions and ran for fourteen episodes before ending.

I'm having trouble finding much info on this show, but [this user review on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw1190211/?ref_=tt_urv) mentions a character named Glitch, and the title of one of the episodes listed on IMDB is "[Glitch Is Alive](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0683822/?ref_=ttep_ep3)."

> This is a series about two kids, Nick and Samantha Bonner, who move into a house and find a special computer. They soon discover that it contains the house's previous owner, an inventor named Jack Craft, who has been trapped in computer for years. **Along with the other citizens of the computer, DEV, Glitch, Isis, and Wil, they are learn various lessons in subjects of math, science, culture, and literature.** I used to watch this show back in 3rd grade, every Saturday morning. I bet those who have seen this show never expected Ryan Seacrest to become so famous. It's a real shame that they cancelled this show. A very unique educational program.

Comment: LogicDictates with it exactly!  As soon as I saw the name I googled before looking at the video... but yeah once I saw the characters I knew this was it.

Now... to see if the episodes are available somewhere.

Oh and one IMDB review incorrectly says it was local.  It was definitely syndicated:  I was well out of range of Atlanta.